# How to access multiselect dropdownlist using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list with multiselect like this:

```
<select id="ddMonths" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="oneM" selected="selected"> OneMonth</option>   
    <option value="twoM" selected="selected">TwoMonths</option>
    <option value="threM" selected="selected">ThreMonths</option>
    <option value="fourM" selected="selected">FourMonths</option>
    <option value="fiveM" selected="selected">FiveMonths</option>     
    <option value="SixM" selected="selected">SixMonths</option>

</select>
```

and the javascript :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddMonths').multiselect();
    });
```

and i have a html table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Something</th>
            <th>Something1</th>
            <th>Something2 </th>
            <th >Something3 </th>
            <th>Something4 </th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody id="trBoth">
        <asp:Literal ID="allSomething" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

I populate the table using the literal in code behind.
I want to control the value of the table using the selected items from multiselect dropdownlist  is it possible??? how can I access the selected items from code behind? I'm using asp.net C#.  Please I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope in this case avoid `DropDownList` and use `ListBox`.

Take a look at the `ListBox` control to allow multi-select.

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lblMultiSelect" SelectionMode="multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="OneM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="TwoM" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="ThreeM" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

in the code behind

```
foreach(ListItem listItem in lblMultiSelect.Items)
{
   if (listItem.Selected == True)
   {
      var val = listItem.Value;
      var txt = listItem.Text; 
   }
}
```

Else go for Dropdown with checkboxes

[jQuery Dropdown Check List](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/)

[System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

Comment: i don't need a ListBox i need a dropdown with multi checkbox... is there any other way to do that???

Comment: thanks for the help, I would have another question I would check with javascript if the listbox has no element selected. if it has no element selected  I wont to  hide the  table. instead of the first I put this to work:   
    
 $ (document) .ready (function () {
         $ ('[id * = lblMultiSelect]'). multiselect ({
             includeSelectAllOption: false,
         
  
     });
  
     });

Comment: @IannaEttius if no element selected in listbox u need to hide a table?when this happen..while clicking a button or page load? also show the code for the table and all

Comment: on page load the table is the same i just put the id  <table id="table" > and when selected item are none i wont to hide the table $('#table').hide();

Comment: @IannaEttius when do u want to hide the table? i understand it need to hide if no item is selected but tell me the event..is it button click or something..also tell me which control u used above for listing

Comment: I cannot do it with an event from a code behind, I need to get the event in javascript. Is there any way to do this without having any button that fires an event, maybe with a control validator that controls when the list is empty, or something like that?

Comment: ok so if when the list is empty u need to hide the table and if anything in list got selected table need to be visible..am i right? tell me which control u used to achieve the above question got solved.

Comment: I haven't used any control, I am asking if using a control validator would get the solution. You are right, but all you said must be done from client side, not from code behind.

Comment: @IannaEttius which control u used for muiltiselect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78231/discussion-between-sachu-and-ianna-ettius).